# Subsequent Tints Not Working

Tags: android

I am adding backwards compatibility for an app and `setTint` is used on a `Drawable` retrieved from a `LayerDrawable`. Code is below.

```
Drawable background = layerDrawable.getDrawable(0);
background = DrawableCompat.wrap(background);
DrawableCompat.setTint(background.mutate(), color);
```

This works the first time but if I then try and change it again afterwards, it doesn't change. Please note, this is the case for Android SDK < 21. 21 and above it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the documentation like a good boy for the `DrawableCompat.wrap` method, I realised I needed to add the "wrapped" drawable back into the `LayerDrawable`.

```
int id = layerDrawable.getId(0);
Drawable background = layerDrawable.getDrawable(0);
background = DrawableCompat.wrap(background);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(id,background);

DrawableCompat.setTint(background.mutate(), color);
```